# Can you deploy an Android application onto Google App Engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Is it possible to deploy an Android application to the google app engine environment? ie to deploy it to appspot?

If not, is there any kind of "container" which would allow one to do this?

I would like to create an application that can be deployed on both android, and a web based environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you develop for App Engine you use Java Servlets (or Python) - when you develop for Android, you use Java with the Android-libraries running on the Dalvik VM.
So no: not without big changes to the code.

But because the App Engine produces HTTP-responses (and therefore you can return HTML) and they can be viewed via Android's webbrowser ;)