# Android Emulator in Browser

Tags: android, android-emulator, cloud, virtual

I would like to showcase my android apps to clients.I would like to send them so that they can play with it in browser and tell the changes.

So,in order to achieve that can a VNC Session of Android be Emulated in browser? If so Can this be done using only javascript with help of node.js or do i need to use java servlets to do that?

I would like to know the possibilities and How can this be done.

**EDIT 1:**

After some googling i found this site which exactly does what i needed.After going through the source of it i think its exactly an emulation of VNC instance in a browser.So have look it and please let me know.

Here is the link to the site http://www.manymo.com/

Comment: I'd recommend investing in a device to showcase your apps. No emulator can match that.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: If you found an solution yourself, post it as an answer (and accept it!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try noVNC: https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC - I belive it has full support for NodeJS and integrates easily into existing sites.

The problem with the approach is that simulators are really slow. I would not risk it to show progress to non-technical customer.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492683/can-you-deploy-an-android-application-onto-google-app-engine) to this a while back, regarding deploying apps to Google App Engine with the intention of creating browser based demos, and it appears that not much has sprung up since then in regards to a viable solution, however the link you post does look interesting.

Your best alternatives are :

1. Buy a (cheap) handset, load up your apps, and demo in front of the
   client.
2. Send them an APK so they can try it on their devices
3. Make some videos, or storyboarding using screenshots of how the app
   works (not great, but it'd give an idea of what you can do)

Nothing substitutes having a demo on a real device :

- They can actually have the app on a phsyical device in their hands,
  they goes a long way..
- They can make use of the device APIs that you may find difficult to
  emulate otherwise if you have complex use cases
- They can run it on a specific device that perhaps they're intending
  to use